# how to create Groups programatically in Django

Tags: django, permissions, models

I am setting up a member site using django, in which members belong to groups that they create and then invite other users to join.

It seems that what I am looking for is to use the django groups functionality, but the documentation on how to go about this is minimal at best - at least I haven't found any. It basically talks about creating groups in the Admin console, which is not what I am trying to do. I would like to do it programatically/dynamically.

Another way to go about this would be to at a foreignkey to the User model up to a group model, however I can't add a foreignkey to the generic User model.

I have read lots of stuff that google threw up at me from my searches. none helpful.

How would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well a `Group` is just another model in Django (one of the models defined in the Django library).

You can thus create a group with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

g1 = Group.objects.create(name='Name of the group')
```

The `Group` model has two many-to-many relations: one to `User`s (with related name `users`), and one to `Permission` (with related name `permissions`). So we can use the corresponding managers to add and remove `User`s and `Permission`s.

Then you can for example populate the group with users like:

```
g1.user_set.add(user1, user2, user5, user7)
```

You can also add permissions to a group with:

```
g1.permissions.add(perm1, perm3, perm4)
```

Comment: I'm using django 1.11, if User.groups exists, Group.users not. But I can do what you suggest using g1.user_set.add(user1, user2)

Comment: @jeanpierrehuart: ah, yes, indeed, in Django-1.11 (and likely previous versions, the `related_name='user_set'`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L233

Comment: @jeanpierrehuart: I think I made a typo in the answer, this is no, thanks to you, fixed :)

Comment: Where in the project should this go? models.py?